# Flattening complex directory

Tags: windows-10

What is the command to flatten a layered directory so all of the files within files are listed in order of the directory?  I've used it before, it was a simple command, maybe used the word "tree"?  I cannot find it ?

Answer (score 2):

In a command prompt:

```
tree [drive:][path] /F
```